# Annotations above inequalities in a chain of inequalities, one slide at a time

Tags: beamer, equations, highlighting, annotations, hf-tikz

I am trying to write a chain of inequalities with the following feature: first, on successive slides, I wish to highlight (for instance, with a tcolorbox) successive inequalities and annotate them with a little explanation above them. I am currently trying to use stackrel for this purpose, but it doesn't highlight stuff, nor does it annotate with math (ie., if the annotation has math inside it, LaTeX throws compilation errors. second, I wish to have the math above this chain of inequalities to be greyed out while I am doing the highlighting (and vice versa, the inequality chain should  be greyed out when I'm showing the block of math above.

I also tried with hf-tikz, but I think it requires the use of array, and I am unable to get everything nicely aligned using array.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% color for the progress bar and the circle

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@rcircle % radius for the circle
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt
\progressbar@rcircle=2.5pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pbblue!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);

    \filldraw[pbblue!30] %
      (\the\dimexpr\progressbar@tmpdim-\progressbar@rcircle\relax, .5\progressbar@pbht) circle (\progressbar@rcircle);

    \node[draw=pbblue!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbblue!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\begin{frame}[t]{Step 3: Packing Potential Tracking}
\textit{Proof.} Motivation 
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= g(x)\\
                        &\leq r(x) &&\text{//$a_j \leq 1/16, \therefore e^{a_j} \leq 1 + a_j + a_j^2$}&\\
                        &\leq m(x) &&\text{//$a^2_j \leq g_j$} 
\end{align*}
Sum over all $j$, take logarithm, and use $\log (1+x)\leq x$.% To see the bounds on $a_j$ and $a^2_j$: 
\[a_j \stackrel{def1}{=} stuff \stackrel{def2}{\leq} stuff \stackrel{def3}{\leq} stuff \stackrel{def4}{\leq}stuff.\] 
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Specifically, I'd like to first have the block of math $f(x)\leq.... m(x)$ be displayed ,while the chain beneath it is greyed out. Then, I'd like the block greyed out, and each of the def1, def2, etc., appear as highlighted in successive slides, with the ability to write a little bit of math in the annotations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `\unvover`s, `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` and replaced `\stackrel` by overset to obtain

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% color for the progress bar and the circle

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@rcircle % radius for the circle
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt
\progressbar@rcircle=2.5pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pbblue!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);

    \filldraw[pbblue!30] %
      (\the\dimexpr\progressbar@tmpdim-\progressbar@rcircle\relax, .5\progressbar@pbht) circle (\progressbar@rcircle);

    \node[draw=pbblue!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbblue!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\begin{frame}[t]{Step 3: Packing Potential Tracking}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}%
\uncover<1>{\textit{Proof.} Motivation 
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= g(x)\\
     &\leq r(x) &&\text{//$a_j \leq 1/16, \therefore e^{a_j} \leq 1
 + a_j + a_j^2$}&\\
    &\leq m(x) &&\text{//$a^2_j \leq g_j$} 
\end{align*}
Sum over all $j$, take logarithm, and use $\log (1+x)\leq x$.}% To see the bounds on $a_j$ and $a^2_j$: 
\uncover<2->{\[a_j \overset{def1}{=} stuff 
\uncover<2,4->{\overset{def2}{\leq} stuff}
\uncover<2,5->{\overset{def3}{\leq} stuff}
\uncover<2,6->{\overset{def4}{\leq}stuff.}\]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark,fit}

\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{pbblue}{HTML}{0A75A8}% color for the progress bar and the circle

\makeatletter
\def\progressbar@progressbar{} % the progress bar
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcounta% auxiliary counter
\newcount\progressbar@tmpcountb% auxiliary counter
\newdimen\progressbar@pbht %progressbar height
\newdimen\progressbar@pbwd %progressbar width
\newdimen\progressbar@rcircle % radius for the circle
\newdimen\progressbar@tmpdim % auxiliary dimension

\progressbar@pbwd=\linewidth
\progressbar@pbht=1pt
\progressbar@rcircle=2.5pt

% the progress bar
\def\progressbar@progressbar{%

    \progressbar@tmpcounta=\insertframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpcountb=\inserttotalframenumber
    \progressbar@tmpdim=\progressbar@pbwd
    \multiply\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcounta
    \divide\progressbar@tmpdim by \progressbar@tmpcountb

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pbblue!30,line width=\progressbar@pbht]
      (0pt, 0pt) -- ++ (\progressbar@pbwd,0pt);

    \filldraw[pbblue!30] %
      (\the\dimexpr\progressbar@tmpdim-\progressbar@rcircle\relax, .5\progressbar@pbht) circle (\progressbar@rcircle);

    \node[draw=pbblue!30,text width=3.5em,align=center,inner sep=1pt,
      text=pbblue!70,anchor=east] at (0,0) {\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,center,dp=1ex]{white}%
    \progressbar@progressbar%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\begin{frame}[t]{Step 3: Packing Potential Tracking}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}%
\uncover<1>{\textit{Proof.} Motivation 
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= g(x)\\
     &\leq r(x) &&\text{//$a_j \leq 1/16, \therefore e^{a_j} \leq 1
 + a_j + a_j^2$}&\\
    &\leq m(x) &&\text{//$a^2_j \leq g_j$} 
\end{align*}
Sum over all $j$, take logarithm, and use $\log (1+x)\leq x$.}% To see the bounds on $a_j$ and $a^2_j$: 
\uncover<2->{\[\tikzmarknode{aj}{a_j} 
    \tikzmarknode{stuff3}{\overset{def1}{=} stuff}
\uncover<2,4->{\tikzmarknode{stuff4}{\overset{def2}{\leq} stuff}}
\uncover<2,5->{\tikzmarknode{stuff5}{\overset{def3}{\leq} stuff}}
\uncover<2,6->{\tikzmarknode{stuff6}{\overset{def4}{\leq} stuff}.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X in {3,...,6}
 {\node[visible on=<\X>,draw,fit=(aj)(stuff\X)] {};}
\end{tikzpicture}\]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Schrodinger's cat, thank you! Sorry, my question wasn't clear; some clarifications: 1) First, the top bunch of math inside the "align" environment is on display (either sequentially, or all at once, not decided yet), while the one-line math at the bottom is to be greyed out. 2) Next, the top bunch of math is to be greyed out, while the bottom line appears clearly (without explanations) 3) Next, while the top align env is still greyed out, I wish to explain the one-line math by highlighting, in sequence, each equality or inequality sign, along with a little box of explanation above it.

Comment: @lazulikid Hmmh, can you perhaps to rephrase this to become unambiguous. For instance, I do not know what the "top bunch" is.

Comment: Hi @Schrodinger's cat, sorry again. Let me rephrase it precisely: let us term all the math above the sentence "sum over all ..." as A and the long chain of equation/inequalities below the sentence as B. Then, I'd like 1) on the first slide, only A and the sentence "sum over ..." appear, while B is greyed out. 2) on the next slide, grey out A and the sentence "sum over...", while displaying B. 3) Next, keeping A and the sentence greyed out, I wish to explain the math in B by highlighting, in sequence, each equality or inequality sign, along with a little box of explanation above it.

Comment: @lazulikid Does the update go in the right direction?

Comment: @Schrodiner's cat: Yes, this is exactly correct!

Comment: Hi @Schrodinger's cat, sorry to bother you again -- do you happen to have any suggestions for making a box around the def and the inequality/equality they are explaining? For instance, when the first "def1" is visible, I'd like a box around "a_j \overset{def1}{\leq} stuff".

Comment: @lazulikid Added.